# ¿Cómo puedo sumar valores numéricos de varios arreglos?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber como sumar valores numéricos de un arreglo con otro o si se pueden convertir a numero 
ejemplo:

```
Array1 = [1,2,3];

Array2=[5,6];
```

Lo que deseo es que sea `123 + 56`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes convertir un array a numero usando esta función:

```
function arrayANumero(array){
    var num = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        // Concatenamos cada uno de los digitos en una cadena
        num += array[i];
    }
    // retornamos la cadena convertida en una numero con parseInt()
    return (parseInt(num))

}
```

Luego de que conviertas cada uno de los arrays simplemente sumas los resultados:

```
arrayANumero([1,2,3]) + arrayANumero([5,6]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Te deje una respuesta completa, para n numeros de arrays

```js
function _j() {
  var i_ = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return i_.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return acc instanceof Array ? +acc.join("") + +cur.join("") :
            !(acc instanceof Array) ? +acc + +cur.join("") : 0;
  });
}

console.log(_j([1,2,3], [5,6], [2,1], [4,9,2], [1,0,0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando el método [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) puedes logralo. Suma cada array independientemente y luego sumas el resultado de ambos:

```js
var Array1 = [1,2,3];
var Array2=[5,6];

var suma = Array1.reduce((x,z)=>x+z,0) + Array2.reduce((x,z)=>x+z,0)

console.log(suma);
```

Comment: pero estás sumando cada digito individualemente lo que sale `17`. y el OP quiere sumar los dos arrays. Lo que haria sería `z.toString()` y a todo el sumando meterlo dentro de `Number( ... )` . Un saludo